# Converting an attribute having values in string form to vetor using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have to prepare data for training the model of linear regression. In data there is attribute 'Gender' having three values 'M','F' and 'I'. How can i convert these values to the respective (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) vector form?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is *not* a tutorial service; please share the code you have tried so far and what your exact issues are.

Comment: The OP asked for conversion advice, not tutorial service.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Arguably, "please give me the code to do *this* and *that*" is a tutorial request (easily obtained online, at least for simple stuff like this), and not a request for advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['M','F','I']}) 
pd.get_dummies(df)

Gender_F    Gender_I    Gender_M
0           0           1
1           0           0
0           1           0
```